# Android Studio APK Analyzer not show details result

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to optimize my app size.For that,I want to analyze my app with android studio analyze apk tool.But it only show the file size not details report.[image]

Comment: It's still loading. Be patient

Comment: @Zun Bro I have waited more than half hour.

Comment: Did you use proguard and minify in your grade file to minimise the app size, your apk seems heavy in size.

Comment: @Abhishek No bro,I have no used proguard yet.

Comment: Then use proguard mate, it will help in optimise your app size.

Comment: The problem isn't whether proguard is there or not :) But same with me just doesnt work. I have proguard and everything size of 60MB. I guess if the size is beyond certain MB the plugin just dies when we try running. Created a Issue @Jabir_Hstu feel free to add your context too. Hopefully they can fix it

https://github.com/android/size-analyzer/issues/14

Comment: @JayshilDave : Did you got any work around ? I have an apk under 60MB but facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://medium.com/@arungiri.10/managing-application-size-50810d03b16c for detailed info.

Use below lines to enable app shrinking using R8.

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    release {
        ...
        useProguard false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ...
    }
}
```

where `proguard-rules.pro` must be written by you based on your app. Generally this file contains lines of code to not obfuscate data / model classes.

Once you do this, a APK will be generated in the output/release directory. Use that APK in APK analyzer tool.

[image]

As we can see the data present inside a APK below.

If you click on classes.dex, it would show the classes present inside this dex file.

[image]

As you can see, the code is proguarded, you will also get option to add respective mapping.txt file which would help in reverse engineering and see the APK package data.

[image]

mapping.txt file is auto-generated and is present under outputs/mapping/release/. Use this to reverse engineer and see the actual class names.

Also, to add proguard rules for data classes, it's easy. Just select the class or package you want to keep from proguarding, right click on it and select "Generate Proguard Keep rule" as shown below.

[image]

Proguard rules will be auto generated, copy this and put it in above proguard-rules.pro file.

[image]

Hope this answer helps.